# Android: Button not showing on view

Tags: android, xml

I'm completely new to Android and am trying to add a simple button to my view, but my view is completely blank.  Here is my setup:

EDIT: I have now changed my code to write this programmatically since I'm used to that with iOS.

I'm now getting the following error:

Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOrientation(int)' on a null object reference

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public Button myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create main view
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Create button
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Fire Call");

        // Add button to view
        linearLayout.addView(myButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if IDE generated fragment.xml for you and insert button there also your button does not have an id! For instance: `android:id="@+id/button_1"`

Comment: I have now updated my question as I have decided to try this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `setContentView` which takes a View or a layout resource id.

Also, you can only call `findViewById` if you provide a layout resource id, and call `setContentView` with it. Alternatively, you could inflate it and call `view.findViewById` on the resulting inflated view.

Here's your code with some changes that should hopefully fix your new issue:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public Button myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create main view
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Create button
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Fire Call");

        // Add button to view
        linearLayout.addView(myButton);

        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, setContentView was my killer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot pinpoint the error but maybe you can.
Try checking after every line you type and see if the button appears. Also check if the problem is with button only or does it extend to other layouts as well.

1. Just type  and see what happens.
2. Follow it up with dimensions.

Don not forget to save after each step. Usually all such problems can be solved by detailed debugging.
If none of the layout appears, try and restart the software.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` , in your code there, you commented it out, so your layout wasnt inflated so you got a blank white screen. Uncomment that line and you will be fine.